# Use JSON after caching through AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax, caching

I'm new in coding and currently creating a website that supports English and Russian languages. I want to change between them with no page reload, so I decided to use AJAX to achieve it and store information in JSON. I have a checkbox that changing my langString between EN and RU depending on checkbox state.

```
var langStr = "en";

        $('#langsw').click(function(){

            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
                langStr = "ru";
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
                langStr = "en";
            }
        });
```

And this is jquery code to perform AJAX part

```
$.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          dataType:'json',
          url: langStr+".json",
          cache:true,
          success: function(data){
              $('#meet').append(data.title);
              $('#meet').append(data.hr);
              $('#meet').append(data.subtitle);
          },
          error: function(data){
            console.log("there is an error")
          }
        });
```

My JSON is

```
  {
    "title":"<h1 style=\"color:white; font-size: 42pt\">Name</h1>",
    "hr":"<hr style=\"width:60%\">",
    "subtitle":"<h1 style=\"color:#dbdbdb; font-weight:100\">Interactive resume</h1>"
  }
```

and the second one is the same in Russian.

Now the question: I want to cache both JSONs and then use one of them depending on the state of the checkbox, but I don't know how to do so. If you have any ideas relating to other ways of achieving this I will be very happy to read them.

P.s English is my 2 language so forgive the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the information in localstorage (altough there is a [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) of how much you can save there).

You can use this formula to save raw json into localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('language-ru', data);
```

To get what is in localstorage you would use

```
const ru = localstorage.getItem('language-ru')
```

So you can check, if user has the right language in his localstorage and if there is nothing, you can download it with that ajax call.

You can read more about localstorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage